# Application insight for .NET Core apps on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core

We have several systems that are used by a few hundred users. We would like to collect insights that cannot be collected by Google Analytics.

For example, we want to store data such as Customer X, click on button Y, in system Z, at time YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:ss

We would like to:

1. Show a summary of metrics on a dashboard. e.g. live stats on a Grafana dashboard
2. Pull detailed reports e.g. Top 5 users that use feature X in system Y (and their usage)

Is there an insight system that I can use and avoid building it from scratch? If I have to build this what is the best way suggested? I am thinking My SQL or SQL Server can be good candidates for the database as Grafana has built-in support for them.